# How to calculate the number of epochs based on the size of training dataset, batch_size and the number of training steps?

Tags: machine-learning, opennmt, nmt

I am new to ONMT, and am a bit confused about the number of epochs and training steps. I know the number of epochs is the number of times that we iterate through the training dataset, but how can I calculate the number of epochs that I trained my model with?

e.g., let's say I have 20000 training samples and my batch_size is 64 and had 3200 training steps. If this is the case, then what is the number of epochs that I trained my model with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The number of periods is set arbitrarily. However, it should be taken into account that if it is too large it will lead to overfiting and if it is too small to underfitting. It is thus judicious to use [callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback) which will make it possible to stop the training on certain criteria of evolution of the precision.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the thing is ONMT only allows me to configure the number of training steps, not the epochs. So I want to know how to calculate the number of epochs based on the number of training steps that I set